# Finding the path on a hexagonal playground?

Tags: mathematics

Ben is at school playground. The playground is a special playground though: Its in a form of a hexagonal grid, and each hexagonal spot has a number. Ben loved the playground, and was even more eager to play on it when the principal came out.

The principal said to everyone in the school to try find the route from the Start to the Finish so that the numbers added up is the smallest value possible and the route that gives them the largest value possible, without going backwards. The principal also said that a huge reward will be given. Ben wants that reward. Can you help him?

This is the playground:

[image: The hexagon playground]

*This puzzle is of my own creation.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The max without going backwards

> is 41 with this path (or alternate path through other 3)
>  [image: ![enter image description here]

The min is

> 10 with the following path
>  [image]

The max (pre-correction) is

> the sum of all the numbers, 115, e.g. with this path or one similar
>  [image]

Comment: i just forgot to add a part of the question, which is that you can't go backwards. I am very sorry I forgot that though! An upvote will be given, but if you would revise the answer to fill in that conditon to earn the checkmark?

Comment: And also check the min part of the puzzle, are you sure its **9** ?